# conversion from Javascript to valid TYPESCRIPT for Angular 6 - G Picker API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**To use G Picker API in the Angular application** inside *app.component.ts*

***app.component.html***

```
<a routerLink="/" id="AllFilePick" #AllFilePick> Button </a>
```

***assets/api-script.js***

```
//=Create object of FilePicker Constructor function function & set Properties===
function SetPicker() {
    var picker = new FilePicker(
        {
            apiKey: '<API_KEY>', 
            clientId: '<CLIENT_ID>',
            buttonEl: document.getElementById("AllFilePick"),
            onClick: function (file) {             
                PopupCenter('https://drive.google.com/file/d/' + file.id + '/view', "", 1026, 500);
            }
        }
    );
}

//====================Create POPUP function==============
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h)
{
    var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
    var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
    return window.open(url, title, 'width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left); 
}

//===============Create Constructor function==============
function FilePicker(User)
{
    //Configuration 
    this.apiKey = User.apiKey;
    this.clientId = User.clientId;

    //Button
    this.buttonEl = User.buttonEl;

    //Click Events
    this.onClick = User.onClick;
    this.buttonEl.addEventListener('click', this.open.bind(this));

    //Disable the button until the API loads, as it won't work properly until then.
    this.buttonEl.disabled = true;

    //Load the drive API
    gapi.client.setApiKey(this.apiKey);
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', this.DriveApiLoaded.bind(this));
    gapi.load('picker', '1', { callback: this.PickerApiLoaded.bind(this) });
}

FilePicker.prototype = {

    //==========Check Authentication & Call ShowPicker() function=======
    open: function () {
        // Check if the user has already authenticated
        var token = gapi.auth.getToken();
        if (token)
        {
            this.ShowPicker();
        } 
        else 
        {
            this.DoAuth(false, function () 
                { this.ShowPicker(); }.bind(this));
        }
    },

    ShowPicker: function () {
        var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;

        //========Show Different Display View in Picker Dialog box=======

        //View all the documents & folders of google drive
        var DisplayView = new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true);
        //========Show Different Upload View in Picker Dialog box=======
        var UploadView = new google.picker.DocsUploadView().setIncludeFolders(true);

        //User can upload file in specific folder
        this.picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            addView(DisplayView).
            enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED).
            setAppId(this.clientId).
            addView(UploadView).
            setOAuthToken(accessToken).
            setCallback(this.PickerResponse.bind(this)).
            setTitle('Google Picker API - BEEP Chat APP').
            build().
            setVisible(true);
    },

    //====Called when a file has been selected in the Google Picker Dialog Box===
    PickerResponse: function (data) 
    {
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) 
        {
            var file = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0],
                id = file[google.picker.Document.ID],
                request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({ fileId: id });
            this.ShowPicker();
            request.execute(this.GetFileDetails.bind(this));
        }
    },

    //====Called when file details have been retrieved from Google Drive.========
    GetFileDetails: function (file) {
        if (this.onClick) {
            this.onClick(file);
        }
    },

    //====Called when the Google Drive file picker API has finished loading.=======
    PickerApiLoaded: function () {
        this.buttonEl.disabled = false;
    },

    //========Called when the Google Drive API has finished loading.==========
    DriveApiLoaded: function () {
        this.DoAuth(true);
    },

    //========Authenticate with Google Drive via the Google Picker API.=====
    DoAuth: function (immediate, callback) {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
            client_id: this.clientId,
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
            immediate: immediate
        }, callback);
    }
};
```

This code is working with normal multi-page web application, but when integrating with the single-page-application, in my case Angular. **I'm not able to run valid Javascript code in Angular Typescript.**

Comment: You're missing the decorator `@Component`. I wonder though, why don't you just rewrite this? So many things that can be refactor.

Comment: It was actually api-script.js instead of app.component.ts